# PHP : Ganon dom parser filter the anchor tags

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I am working with PHP Dom Parser library and i have a complex HTML structure to parse :

```
<table width="640" style="color: #333333;">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top">
<font face="Arial,Helevetica,sans-serif">
<a href="http://forums.timezone.com/index.php?t=tree&amp;goto=6577581&amp;rid=0">20mm Omega SMP Bond Bracelet Ref. 1503-825- PRICE DROP</a><br>
<font size="-1" color="#999999">Sales Corner - <a href="http://forums.timezone.com/index.php?t=usrinfo&amp;id=462&amp;rid=0">The Bigwatch Guy</a></font><font size="-1" color="#999999"> - Aug 7, 2013</font><br>
<font size="-1">20mm OMEGA SEAMASTER PROFESSIONAL "BOND" BRACELET REF. 1503-825. All s/s genuine Bond bracelet in excellent condition. The bracelet is 6.6 inches long...</font>
<br>
<br>
</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<font face="Arial,Helevetica,sans-serif">
<a href="http://forums.timezone.com/index.php?t=tree&amp;goto=6577577&amp;rid=0">Longines Lindbergh Hour Angle Chronograph- PRICE DROP</a><br>
<font size="-1" color="#999999">Sales Corner - <a href="http://forums.timezone.com/index.php?t=usrinfo&amp;id=462&amp;rid=0">The Bigwatch Guy</a></font><font size="-1" color="#999999"> - Aug 7, 2013</font><br>
<font size="-1">42mm (not counting the crown) LONGINES LINDBERGH HOUR ANGLE AUTOMATIC CHRONOGRAPH W/ COMPLETE BOXSET AND PAPERS - NEARMINT PLUS CONDITION. The strap h...</font>
<br>
<br>
</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to get all the anchor tags whose href attribute contains `goto` string 
, I have tried with below code :

```
<?php 
include("ganon.php");
$html = file_get_dom('http://forums.timezone.com/search/?q=Public+Forum&f=4&s=0');
$c=1;
if( count($html("table[width='640']"))>0 ){
    foreach($html("a[href=*goto]") as $elm){
            echo $c.')'.$elm->href.'<br/>';
    $c++;
    }
}
?>
```

The above code is throwing this notice : `Notice: Expected identifier at 7! in D:\xampp\htdocs\govberg\ganon.php on line 2196` with no other output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Selectors [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/ganon/wiki/Selectors), you can see that:

> **`E[foo*="bar"]`** : An E element whose "foo" attribute value contains the substring "bar"

You're using it incorrectly.

Change the following line:

```
foreach($html("a[href=*goto]") as $elm){
```

to:

```
foreach($html('a[href*="goto"]') as $elm)
```

Output: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ShrCGALi)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oops.. I must checked with selector, anyway you made my day :-)
Thanks